# Remove a column from select statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle11g

I would like to know is there a way to remove a specific column when displaying in a datagridview. Below is the sql statemnt to retrieve

```
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from BHR_2016_FEB_CIT4114_FYP_GD", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
oda.Fill(dt);
dt.Columns.Remove("Fingerprint_Template");
dataGridViewAttendanceDatabase.DataSource = dt;
```

The reasons is because, i have a type of format CLOB, therefore it will not display in datagridview. So i plan remove a column which stores the CLOB format. I can specify, but the problem i will be selecting table based on combo box and each table have different number of columns such as a table might have 31 column, another table might have 28 column. So how i could remove only a single column. Thanks in advanced.

There is still an error as when i state select *, it includes the column which consist of CLOB format. Therefore error exist at oda.Fill(dt);. Is there a way to select * except a columns which consist of CLOB format. This help is really appreciated.

Comment: is the column name same in all those tables?

Comment: yup the column name that i want remove is same in all the tables.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do this

```
dt.Columns.Remove("xyz");
```

**Update**

It seems Fill does not support CLOB data. Above solution will not work.You need to do change in SQL itself. My suggestion is to move everything in stored procedure and use meta data to extract column which you want (or exclude column which you do not want.) Here is sample code. Please note I have not tested it so you may find some minor issue but the code gives you gist of what you can do to solve your problem

**C# Code**

```
 OleDbConnection oc= new OleDbConnection("[pass your connection string]");
 OleDbCommand ocom = new OleDbCommand();
   ocom.CommandText = "Abc"; // Abc is stored procedure  
   ocom.Connection  = oc;
   ocom.CommandType = CommandType.StoreProcedure;
   ocom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName","PQR") // pass your table name
   ocom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@databaseName","IJK"); // pass your database name
 OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(ocom);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            oda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridViewAttendanceDatabase.DataSource = dt;
```

**SQL Script**

```
Create Porocedure Abc (@tableName varchar(255),@databaseName varchar(255))
Begin 

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'Fingerprint_Template,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @databaseName), CONCAT(' FROM ',@tableName));

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

End
```

Comment: sir, can i know like if i do this, in the database table there will be still the column right sir, only in displaying in the datagridview it wont display right sri?

Comment: Yes....This is just going to remove column from data table which you will display and won't affect database

Comment: k sir i trying it now.

Comment: sir i getting the exception Column 'Fingerprint_Template' does not belong to table.

Comment: Either column does not exist in the table or you are referring wrong table

Comment: owh.. still not sure why sir, i have tested it with exact table name, and column name but still not working..

Comment: sir this is correct right sir the place to put the code

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Remove("Fingerprint_Template");  
                oda.Fill(dt);

Comment: sir thanks, but if i place after the fill i am getting error as it is trying to put a column which is in clob format so is it possible to put before the fill as the column Fingerpritn_Template is in CLOB format which visual studio does not allows it into datagridview

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Please post updated code....you are doing something wrong....you have to remove column after fill method call but before setting datasource of grid view...

Comment: are you still getting error? if yes, the post the exact error and stack trace

Comment: yup sir i getting the error still at the line oda.Fill(dt);. I found the problem why getting but dont know how to solve. The problem is at a column which is in CLOB format. If that column does not exist, all works fine, since the column is there that the reasosn i getting the error. The column is crucial as it is used to compare the fingerprint but not necessary for the user to view it.

Comment: Ok I think Fill method itself does not support CLOB data...solution I suggested will not work.....You need to find approach to do this in SQL itself. I think you need to use informatiion schema table and dynamically remove that column and construct the SQL query dynamically.....Do you have permission to run query in master database?

Comment: thanks for the reply, sir can i know like the create procedure usually it will be placed where or any reference for me to read before applying

Comment: I think you need to go thru tutorials for C# n SQL....There are lots of tutorial online....Why do you care how SQL will store that procedure?

Comment: i tried to place the method, i think i missing any namespace, c# and sql that i learnt already.

Comment: If you have already learnt it then why do you have confusion on where Stored Procedure should be created...It is very basic stuff...My honest suggestion is to go online and study again....No one is going to help you in basic stuffs which is already available online.....

Comment: owh... k maybe that i did not learn before... now got it... Thanks sir, i will learnt first for the stored procedure... Thanks sir